# How can I re render same component page in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to re-render the component.

When selecting menu, I use same component.
The component name is 'Performance'.

Navigation.js

```
<Menu.Item as={Link} to='/'>Home</Menu.Item>

        <Dropdown item simple text='Performance'>
          <Dropdown.Menu>
            <Dropdown.Item as={Link} to='/evaluation/performance/item/bp'>BP</Dropdown.Item>               
            <Dropdown.Item as={Link} to='/evaluation/performance/item/rfl'>RFL</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item as={Link} to='/evaluation/performance/item/srw'>SRW</Dropdown.Item>
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
      </Container>
    </Menu>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} exact={true} />
      <Route path="/evaluation/:evaluation/item/:item" component={Performance} />
    </Switch>
```

And Performance.js

```
class Performance extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.state = {
     evaluation: ''
      ,evaluationItem: ''
      ,isLoading: false
    };
  }
   shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
     if(this.props.match.params.item !=nextProps.match.params.item){
     console.log(this.props.match.params.item +',' +nextProps.match.params.item);   
     }
     return true;
   }
 render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper className="Performance">        
          {this.state.isLoading ? <Loadering /> : null}        
        <div>
          <TestCases/>
        </div>
        <SplitPane split="vertical" defaultSize={"25%"} minSize={"20px"} >
          <SplitPane
            split="horizontal"
            defaultSize={"30%"}
          >

            <div className='test-env'>
              <TestEnv/>
            </div>
            <div className='-data'>
              <Data/>
            </div>
          </SplitPane>
          <div className='chart-content'>
            <PerformanceChart />
          </div>
        </SplitPane>
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
};
export default Performance;
```

I want to re-render when changing menu.
First, I selected BP menu after then I selected SRW menu.
Again select BP, the page shows previous view. 
I mean component is not re-render.
I want to see the new BP page.

Plus. When I use Link, the console shows warinig.

Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of .

It occurs the Dropdown.Item ... 
does Anyone know reason?

Comment: you want to re render which component ?

Comment: I want to re render 'Performance' component.(Parent component). I think Parent component does not re render well....

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the first `<Route>` tag, change "excact" to "exact".

To force update,

```
<Dropdown.Item as={Link} to={{pathname: '/evaluation/performance/item/bp', state: 'refresh'}}>
BP
</Dropdown.Item>
```

and in the BP component:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (nextProps.location.state === 'refresh') {
    return prevState;
  }
  return null;
}
```

For the warning, check your DOM if you have a `div` inside a `span` or `p` because that's not what you should have.

Comment: Oh...typing error.... ;o; Thanks.. Also, I remove where  ' <Dropdown item simple text='Performance' as={Link} name='bp' to='/performance'>' -> ' <Dropdown item simple text='Performance' >'.

Comment: Did it work? Have you tried adding state prop to dropdown item?